# Access data after sql query in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have performed the sql statement below and it has obtained the relevant row from the table.

sql;

```
$user = $this->UserVerifications
                ->find()
                ->where(['code' => $hash])
                ->all();
```

It is getting the row from the table 'UserVerifications' where the column 'code' is equal to the value of 'hash'. This bit works, see below for output.

```
debug($user);
\src\Controller\UsersController.php (line 57) object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet) {

'items' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\UserVerification) {

        'id' => (int) 23,
        'code' => '4206e38996fae4028a26d43b24f68d32',
        'date_created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2016-11-21T18:48:45+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'UserVerifications'

    }
]

}
```

According to the CakePHP website, or at least the way I'm reading it, I should be able to access the value for id by doing the following;

```
echo $user->id;
```

Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\ResultSet::$id [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 58]

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need particular row only from table,try this:

```
$user = $this->UserVerifications
            ->find()
            ->where(['code' => $hash])
            ->first();
```

And now you can use:

```
$user->id;
```

to access value of id and so on. And if you need multiple rows from the table go with @Felippe's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$user` is a collection/ResultSet, not a UserVerifications instance.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

You should iterate over it, like:

```
foreach($user as $u) {
    echo $u->id;
}
```